# MongoDB: Speed up aggregate by Indexing or find a different solution?

Tags: mongodb

Ok, MongoDB experts, please take a look at my collection:

```
[{
  "_id" : "item_0",
  "Name" : "Item 0",
  "Description" : "Some description for this item...",
  "Properties" : {
    "a" : 5.0,
    "b" : 0.0,
    "c" : 6.0,
    "d" : 6.0,
    "e" : 2.0,
    "f" : 0.0,
    "g" : 9.0,
    "h" : 3.0,
    "i" : 4.0,
    "j" : 5.0
  }
},
{ // 5.000-10.000 more items... }
]
```

I am using this aggregate to multiply a set of selected properties (in this case a, b, c and d), to then sort them by their product:

```
{
    "aggregate": "item",
    "pipeline": [
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "Name": 1,
                "s": {
                    "$multiply": [
                        "$Properties.a",
                        "$Properties.b",
                        "$Properties.c",
                        "$Properties.d"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
                "s": -1
            }
        },
        {
            "$limit": 100
        }
    ]
}
```

Now this works fine and all, but when the number of items and properties increase the time to execute the aggregate will be increased a lot!

Is there any better way (**more efficient**) to achieve something like this? The **search** for the highest product (multiple of a set of properties) must be snappy. If there is a way to index this, with all different combinations of properties and have them cached or something? It's OK that the indexing takes a while, as long as the querying is fast!

Thanks for any help in this matter, I appreciate it a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given your requirement for faster searching and efficiency, I think a better approach would be to use Map/Reduce with an output collection (at least until such time as the Aggregation Framework supports using a collection for output).

There are several advantages to using an output collection for your use case.

In particular:

- you can have flexible indexing and sorting
- the results do not have to be calculated in real-time for every query
- you are not limited by the 16Mb BSON document size for inline results

You can use the [`merge` output option](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/MapReduce#MapReduce-Outputoptions) for Map/Reduce to update calculations in your output collection (essentially, this would be your cache).

Depending on how often your various properties are updated, I would investigate an incremental approach based on a "last updated" timestamp or some other criteria that allows you to determine when values need to be recalculated.  This would allow you to keep the batch sizes more manageable as your collection grows.

Comment: As Sammaye mentioned, there is an open feature request for the Aggregation Framework to support an `$out` option to save results to an output collection.  See [SERVER-2353](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3253) in the MongoDB issue tracker to vote on this feature or watch for updates.

Comment: The idea is that every time a user search, he will select a few properties as the examples above - they can change any time (if the user searches for something else). The values of the properties won't change. Is this still possible with map/reduce. I mean, it would require me to store the results for each different set of selected properties combinations right?

Comment: Hrm .. if you wanted to select from indexed results you would have to be precalculating the combinations. That would be possible with M/R but the number of combinations may be unwieldy depending on your use case (i.e. any of 20 properties, or always a combination of 5). The problem with your requirement is that in order to find a match the server will have to calculate the properties on all documents and then do an in-memory sort to find your top N results. Since your goal is to optimize for speed I would reconsider your schema and whether there might be a better way to represent the data.

Comment: Thinking on this a tad further given your updated use case information in the comment above .. if your practical goal is 10,000 items with 20 properties, that may not be a massive data set in terms of RAM usage. Rather than guessing that it may be slow, you should do some usage tests.  If the whole data set fits in memory and you have to iterate it to get the results anyway, then you likely are close to optimal already.

Comment: Yeah, I will simply have to test this further in the production environment. My laptop does a search like this on 2000 documents in about 170ms, which is actually quite good. The reason I asked in the first place was that it seemed kinda unnecessary to do the multiplication on each document each time the "selected"/queried properties changes. I think this solution will work fine in combination with some caching on the C# server-end. Thanks for your input!